Using S3DeleteObjectsOperator to only delete files and not the subfolder
Is there a way to use S3DeleteObjectsOperator in Airflow to just delete files and not the subfolder in s3?
delete_operator = S3DeleteObjectsOperator(
    task_id=f't0_s3_cleanup_task_{{keys}}',
    aws_conn_id='aws_s3',
    bucket=var_s3_bucket,
    prefix=var_qa_prefix
    )
delete_operator.execute(context)


This could be achieved by using folders in S3, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-folders.html

When you create a folder in Amazon S3, S3 creates a 0-byte object with
a key that's set to the folder name that you provided. For example, if
you create a folder named photos in your bucket, the Amazon S3 console
creates a 0-byte object with the key photos/. The console creates this
object to support the idea of folders.

